# Finding out source of an IP address

Tags: ip, spam

I have an IP address and time of being spammed that I'd like to find out who it bleongs to.
I found that the IP belongs to the ISP: cogeco cable and that it is a commercial account.

Is it possible to find out which company is responsible?

I know I can report to the ISP the IP but I'd like to find out who is responsible in particular.

Comment: if that is not an assigned subnet that has been declared to ARIN or the given authority the only way would be to go thru the ISP or try to find websites or anything within that ip.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Only the ISP would know.  You should report it and work with the ISP to track it down.  ISP's are (generally) very interested in stopping spam that originates from within their subnets.

Comment: +1, Report it to the ISP. They will almost certainly **not** give you the customer's information; but will almost certainly pass a (civil) message along to the customer. If the spam is becoming offensive, contact the police, they have the ability to "contact" the customer.

Comment: +1 have reported issues to Cogeco abuse in the past and they have been very helpful.  However, they will not reveal who the client is.

Answer (score 1):

Try going to [DNSstuff](http://www.dnsstuff.com) and using their "WHOIS" and "IP Information" tools.  That may give you a little more info.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try Domain Tools' [Reverse IP](http://www.domaintools.com/reverse-ip/)

Answer (score 0):

As Prix has stated, unless the IP is part of an assigned blocked of IP's that has been declared to ARIN, and is part of the ISP's dynamic range all you can do is report the problem to the ISP then block the IP on your firewall.

If you think it might be allocated to a specific company then check the [ARIN Database](https://ws.arin.net/whois/)

Answer (score 0):

Doing a lookup at [robtex](http://www.robtex.com) may show you domains that use that IP, which could lead you to an answer.  However, I agree with other answers, just send along your complaint to the ISP, they're the ones who can do something about it.